# CSS with overflow hidden

Tags: css

How to display the last visible  li elements of   div container with "overflow:hidden" otherwise said -  align it to the bottom?

```
<ul style="height:20px; overflow:hidden;">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>this eventually should be visible</li>
<li>this should be visible</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have invalid markup, `li` elements are only allowed inside `ul`s. Also, why would you want to do this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want the height restricted to 20px? or do you want it the same height as your list of <li>s?

Comment: Can you try `overflow: scroll` instead of `hidden`. And `height: 20px` is really a small value. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jy83wwye/)

Comment: Maulzal restricted to 20px
 Ahbi Not something intended in my application

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the purpose of this is or how you intend to show the other `li` but....Flexbox can do that.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>this eventually should be visible</li>
  <li>this should be visible</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hm, not exactly nice to maim an `ul` like this, but on the other hand it does the job quite nicely. Since no other nice/clean options come to my mind, i +1.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
var outerHeight = 0;
var maxheight = 22;
$($("li").get().reverse()).each(function() { 
outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
if(outerHeight >= maxheight) {  
$(this).remove();
}
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arpecop/jy83wwye/1/

if there is CSS way please reply